# How to include props callback within React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I'm new to React and I'm trying to pass data from child component to child component via App (parent) through props with React Router. As far as I know you have to callback the props from child to app and again to child.

The main problem is how to get props from Child.js to App.js with callback and React Router.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value_key: ""
    }
  }

  resultCallback = (result) => {
    this.setState({value_key: result});
    console.log(result)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="container">
            <Header/>
            <Route path="/qr" component={QrReader} functionCallFromParent={this.resultCallback.bind(this)}/>
            <Route path="/nfc" component={NfcReader}/>
            <Output valueFromParent={this.state.value_key}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
      
    );
  }
  
}
```

Child.js

```
export class QrComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    result: 'No result'
  }
 
  handleScan = (data) => {
    this.props.functionCallFromParent(data)
    console.log('Callback from QrReader')
  }

  handleError = err => {
    console.error(err)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <QrReader
          delay={300}
          onError={this.handleError}
          onScan={this.handleScan}
          // onScan={this.handleScan}
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently passing the `functionCallFromParent` prop to the `Route` component. One way to solve this is by wrapping the component and passing the prop directly like so:

```
<Route path="/qr" component={props => <QrReader functionCallFromParent={this.resultCallback.bind(this)} {...props} />} />
```